# GCC no reorder stack variables

Tags: c, gcc, stack

Hi i'm trying to compile a C code without reordering my variables in stack but can't do it.

I've tryed using:

> `__attribute__((no_reorder))`

But doesn't work, also tryed to compile with the flag:

> -fno-toplevel-reorder

But didn't work... so i'm stuck.

Actual code:

```
uint8_t __attribute__((no_reorder)) first_buf[64];
uint8_t second_buf[32];
```

This is my compiler version:

```
gcc (Debian 7.2.0-19) 7.2.0
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: a workaround would be to put those variables in a structure. structure fields order are preserved.

Comment: I've never used this attribute ever, but how could you tell a single variable to not reorder? Seems like you'd have to apply that attribute to a group of variables, or maybe even a function.. ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes that would be my last chance!

Comment: @yano basically gcc is moving that  first_buf after second_buf so yes it should be possible to say just don't move me this variable another option as you said is just in the function declaration add the attribute to the whole procedure but also didn't work

Answer (score 3):

**-fno-stack-protector** will do it. It will cancel stack canary and reordering of buffer on stack.

add that flag when you compile. i.e.

```
gcc myprogram.c -fno-stack-protector
```

Answer (score 2):

from the gcc documentation here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html

> no_reorder
>
> Do not reorder functions or variables marked no_reorder **against each other** or top level assembler statements the executable. The
>   actual order in the program will depend on the linker command line.
>   Static variables marked like this are also not removed. This has a
>   similar effect as the -fno-toplevel-reorder option, but only applies
>   to the marked symbols.

(emphasis mine)

So it would appear that you would need to apply the attribute to the variables the respective order of which you want preserved. Applying the attribute to only a single variable will only preserve the order of that variable with itsef, which has no effect.